# Create a slice of slice with sufficient lifetime

Tags: rust, slice, lifetime

I have a function `foo` that takes in parameter an array slice of array slices, however I can't seem to create a variable that lives long enough to pass it as a parameter:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut outer_vec = vec![];
    for i in 0..10 {
        let inner_vec = vec![i];
        outer_vec.push(inner_vec.as_slice());
    }
    foo(&outer_vec);
}

fn foo(_bar: &[&[u8]]) {
    println!("foo");
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0597]: `inner_vec` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 |         outer_vec.push(inner_vec.as_slice());
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
6 |     }
  |     - `inner_vec` dropped here while still borrowed
7 |     foo(&outer_vec);
  |         ---------- borrow later used here
```

I know that a given inner array slice cannot outlive the lifetime of the `inner_vec` it originates from, which is dropped at the end of the for loop, but I want to know if it is possible to fix this error without changing the signature of the `foo` function, that is, keep it `foo(_bar: &[&[u8]])` and not change it to something like `foo(_bar: &[Vec<u8>])`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with function `foo`. It exists inside `for` loop. Comment out calling `foo` and you will still have an error. In every iteration you create local variable `inner_vec` that is dropped at the end of the iteration. You therefore cannot store a reference to it that would escape the `for` loop. In other words it's lifetime is to short.

The solution here would be to give the ownership of `inner_vec` to `outer_vec` by moving it (not the reference). Then you would have to change `foo`'s signature as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I succeeded in making it work and keeping the same signature for `foo` in the answer I posted, can you take a look at it please?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the same signature for `foo`, you can create a variable that keeps the ownership of the `inner_vec`s and create slices from it in another variable:

```
fn main() {
    let mut outer_vec = vec![];
    for i in 0..10 {
        let inner_vec = vec![i];
        outer_vec.push(inner_vec);
    }
    let vec_of_slices: Vec<&[u8]> = outer_vec.iter()
        .map(|inner_vec| inner_vec.as_slice()).collect();
    foo(&vec_of_slices);
}

fn foo(_bar: &[&[u8]]) {
    println!("foo");
}
```

Comment: Yes. This will work, and I don't see anything glaringly bad here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Vec::leak()` and a turbofish to force the slice to live forever:

```rust
let vec_of_slices =
    outer_vec.iter()
    .map(|inner_vec| inner_vec.leak::<'static>())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

One downside to this, of course, is that, as the name of the `leak()` method suggests, you’d be leaking memory by doing this.

Also note that `Vec::leak()` returns a mutable slice — if you need an immutable slice, you can instead use `slice::from_raw_parts()`:

```rust
let vec_of_slices =
    outer_vec.iter()
    .map(|inner_vec| unsafe {
        use core::mem::ManuallyDrop;
   
        let inner_vec = ManuallyDrop::new(inner_vec);
        
        core::slice::from_raw_parts::<'static>(
            inner_vec.as_ptr(),
            inner_vec.len()
        )
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Note that this call to `slice::from_raw_parts()` needs to be marked `unsafe` since it deals with raw pointers. This is really a duplication of how `Vec::leak()` is defined, only in the upstream case `slice::from_raw_parts_mut()` is used.